# Swift - Could someone help me understand how .sorted(by:) works in this example?

Tags: swift, swift3

This piece of code sorts an array of strings by placing strings with a specific prefix 'searchTerm' at the beginning of the array, and strings that don't have that prefix at the end. Can someone explain how this function works? I'm new at developing in Swift if you couldn't already tell, so please keep the explanation as SIMPLE as possible. Thank you!

```
stringArray = stringArray.sorted(by: {
    switch ($0.hasPrefix(searchTerm), $1.hasPrefix(searchTerm) {
        case (true, true): return $0 < $1 ;
        case (true, false): return true ;
        case (false, true): return false ;
        case (false, false): return $0 < $1
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sorted(by:)` function takes a closure as its input parameter, where you can define your own sorting function. The function iterates through the array in element pairs.

`$0` and `$1` are so called *anonymous closure parameters*, in this case, `$0` is the current element and `$1` is the next element.

The switch statement checks whether the current or the next element starts with the string that's stored in the `searchTerm` variable.

The different states of the switch statement define how the elements should be sorted. If both or neither of the elements have the prefix, they are alphabetically sorted. If only one of them has the prefix, the one that has it will come first in the sorted array.

Hope my explanation was sufficient, if not, just tell me what should I clarify in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent explanation. I have a question concerning the return values in the switch statement. My understanding is that when '$0 < $1' is returned is when the values are sorted alphabetically correct? Also, if my understanding is correct, will switching those bool values (true to false and false to true) reverse the order and make it so strings with the prefix are placed at the end of the array and string without the prefix at the beginning? Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, when `$0 < $1` is returned, the values are sorted alphabetically. Your second assumption is also correct, if you switch the bool values, the sorting based on the prefix will be reversed, but the alphabetical sorting will be kept for the case when both or neither elements have the prefix.

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate the help

Comment: Hey Dávid I hate to have to ask you for more help after you've already answered my initial posting, but could I ask you another question? I'm trying to figure out how I could rewrite this code so the strings with the search term at the prefix appear first, and strings containing the search term appear after. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just flip the `true` and `false` return values and you should be good.

Comment: Not all strings in the array contain the search term. Some strings are in that array because they have tags that contain the search term, so flipping those bool values won't sort it the way I mentioned above.

Comment: Ohh I just reread your comment again, and realised what you want. You should ask a new question for this one, since it's quite different from the current question.

Answer (score 2):

The sorted method you are using runs through the array sorting the items according to the criteria you provide in the block. This block needs to return `true` if one item ($0) should be ordered before the other ($1)

Since you are sorting first on if there is a prefix before the value of the string the comparison is being made like this:

```
switch ($0.hasPrefix(searchTerm), $1.hasPrefix(searchTerm) {
    case (true, true): return $0 < $1 ; // If both items have the prefix, just sort them the way strings are normally sorted
    case (true, false): return true ; // Since the first item has a prefix and the second does not, it should appear before the second one, so return true.
    case (false, true): return false ; // Since the second item has a prefix, and the first one does not, the first item should be sorted after the second, so return false
    case (false, false): return $0 < $1 // Since neither items have a prefix, just sort them the way strings are normally sorted.
}
```

An alternative way to do this which might be clearer:

```
array.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
    switch (first.hasPrefix("p"), second.hasPrefix("p")) {
    case (true, true), (false, false): return first < second
    case (true, false): return true
    case (false, true): return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
stringArray = stringArray.sorted(by: {
```

Here, you are reassigning `stringArray` to be the sorted version of itself. The inclusion of the `by` parameter indicates to Swift that you would like it to use your own sorting order instead of the default one (in this case, things that begin with "searchTerm" come before anything else).

To describe your sorting order, you use a comparison function -- a piece of code that takes two elements from your array and compares them. Let's call these `elementA` and `elementB`. If `elementA` should come before `elementB`, your code should return `true`. If `elementB` should come before `elementA`, your code should return `false`. By using your code to determine which elements come before other elements, Swift can sort your array based on this specification.

```
switch ($0.hasPrefix(searchTerm), $1.hasPrefix(searchTerm) {
```

This line takes the two elements (`$0` and `$1`) and checks if they begin with "searchTerm." For each case, the two booleans in the expression indicate if `$0` and `$1` start with "searchTerm" respectively.

```
case (true, true): return $0 < $1 ;
```

Both of these elements start with "searchTerm," so you want to return the *natural ordering* (i.e. alphabetical ordering). You let Swift use the standard comparison operator, because `$0 < $1` will return `true` if `$0` comes before `$1` and `false` otherwise.

```
case (true, false): return true ;
```

`$0` starts with "searchTerm," but `$1` does not. You want `$0` to come before `$1`, so you return `true`.

```
case (false, true): return false ;
```

`$0` does not start with "searchTerm," but `$1` does. You want `$1` to come before `$0`, so you return `false`.

```
case (false, false): return $0 < $1
```

Neither `$0` nor `$1` start with "searchTerm", so you use natural ordering again.

Comment: This was a big help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`sorted(by:)` lets you specify your own sorting criteria. It performs the sorting by repeatedly asking you how certain elements compare to each other, by running the closure you gave it and passing in the elements as parameters.

This closure comes down to four possible cases:

- #### `case (true, true): return $0 < $1`

  If both `$0` and `$1` start with `searchTerm`, then the ordering between them is decided by regular string comparison (`$0 < $1`)
- #### `case (true, false): return true`

  If `$0` starts with `searchTerm`, but `$1` doesn't, then `$0` should come *before* `$1`
- #### `case (false, true): return false`

  If `$0` starts with `searchTerm`, but $1 doesn't, then `$1` should come *after* `$0`
- #### `case (false, false): return $0 < $1`

  If neither `$0` nor `$1` start with `searchTerm`, then the ordering between them is decided by regular string comparison (`$0 < $1`)